# Can I test chaincode outside of hyperledger environment? No docker, just some mocks

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Can I test chaincode outside of hyperledger environment? No docker, just some mocks.

Even though docker instances are light, I'd like to be able to execute chaincode against some primitive mocks. Especially in the beginning when I'm learning and will make more mistakes.

This is general question unspecific to the language (Go, Node, Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can test the chaincode with mocks without setting up the dev network ([dev-mode](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/chaincode4ade.html)), but I know the answer specifically for Go.

For go you develop the test using [mock stub](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim#MockStub)

Now follow the tips from [go testing](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/):

Name the test with the pattern: `chaincodeName_test.go`

Now you go in the directory and run the Go command: `go test`

You can see this approach in this chaincode dir: [trustreputationledger](https://github.com/pavva91/trustreputationledger/blob/master/trustreputationledger_test.go)